# Which book is best for learning to manipulate graphs of functions from beginner to advanced?

Tags: graphing-functions, book-recommendation, curves

I wanted to learn how we can squeeze and rotate any curve. I got inspired from a YouTube video about batman equation but I think I should study such techniques properly from a book please suggest me a book. I know this question is short and likely to get closed but please just tell me a good book and if people get frustrated I will delete the question

Comment: I doubt that there is such a book. Such skills will lead you to the dark side.

Comment: I edited the title to say "graphs of functions" rather than just "graphs", in order to clarify the question isn't about graphs in the sense of graph theory.